# Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json missing Manage Nuget Packages

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to access appsettings.json using following article
https://makolyte.com/csharp-when-setbasepath-and-addjsonfile-are-missing-for-configurationbuilder/
However, when I try to browse `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` it's not there. I can using `Install-Package` to get it though.

Can someone share some insight as to why this is?

Comment: what type project are you attempting to add it to?

Comment: .net console app